# Is there any contradiction against too many values in a table (database)?

Tags: database

I was wondering if there's any contradiction or futur problems against a table in a database which contains about 80 columns. There will be only VARCHARs, few INT and maybe 1 or 2 MESSAGE. I did some research on the net but there's nothing really talking about that kind of problem...In other terms, is this okay or even 'normal' to put that much of values inside a table??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is too abstract. If your entity may have that many attributes and your DB is normalized - it's a valid data schema.

Comment: SQL is big on relational tables, you should take full advantage of that. *Personally,* I go nuts having to manage more than 12 columns; but that's just *moi.* A baker's dozen, that... I'll make an exception.

Comment: In my experience, a single table should not have that many columns. Not that there's a specific problem with it, just that it tends to indicate deeper issues in either your normalisation or business logic.

Comment: Also, I don't see why you included a tag for PHP since the question isn't related to PHP at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489003/sql-optimization-how-many-columns-on-a-table

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any real problems if the fields are mostly integers.  Most DBMSes have a limit on row length, so a bunch of long columns can cause issues...but unless the `varchar` columns are very long, you're probably OK.

I've honestly never even needed to think about that, though -- with a properly normalized database, it's quite rare to ever need that many columns in a table.

Comment: Actually, it's for a insurance car website so..every customer, if they fill up the forms entirely, there's exactly 78 fields.

Comment: @B.Matthieu: I bet not every customer fills in every field, though.  There are probably groups of fields that are only applicable in certain cases.  And if they only apply sometimes, then they're not integral to the definition of a customer, and might be better off grouped in their own table.

Answer (score 0):

More columns you have, more memory server needs to process the records.

I recomend to use the "multiple to one" relation scheme in this case.

Example of tables:

```
customer
  id
  name
  email
  ...

ins_app_form (Insurance application form)
  id
  customer_id (relation with customer)
  date
  ... (here comes some other data if you need)

ins_app_item (Insurance application form items/fields)
  id
  ins_app_form_id (relation with Insurance application form)
  question (the name of a question in application form)
  answer (customer's answer)
```

So to show the application form with this scheme you will need to run a query:

```
SELECT
  iaf.id AS application_id,
  iaf.date AS `date`,
  iai.question,
  iai.answer
FROM ins_app_form AS iaf
  LEFT JOIN ins_app_item AS iai ON iai.ins_app_form_id=iaf.id
WHERE iaf.customer_id=<ID of a customer>
```

This query will bring you something like this:

```
id  date         question       answer
1   2014-03-31   "Year"         "2008"
1   2014-03-31   "Car make"     "Audi"
1   2014-03-31   "Car model"    "Q7"
...
```

Comment: For reference: this is a variant of a pattern called "EAV" (for "entity, attribute, value").  It works decently if the questions vary per user and you don't need the database to enforce the validity of answers.  Downsides: (1) A lot of the stuff MySQL can do to keep invalid data from creeping in, becomes difficult-to-impossible when every answer ends up in the same column. (2) Each value takes up a *row*, rather than a column, making CRUD operations more complex.