# Is it normal to have a table with about 40-50 columns in database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Is it normal to have a table with about  40-50 columns  in database?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489003/sql-optimization-how-many-columns-on-a-table - you should get most of your queries answered in this question

Comment: Also, related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331323/how-many-columns-are-too-many-for-a-sql-2005-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your data model. It is somehow "neater" to have data broken down into multiple tables and have them related to each other, but it can also be possible your data is such it cannot, or it makes no sense, to be broken down.

If you want to have less columns just "for the sake of it", and there is no significant performance degradations - no need. If you find yourself using less columns than there are in the table, break it down...

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for a database to be de-normalised to improve performance: munging tables together results in fewer joins during queries.

So denormalised tables tend to have more columns, and duplicate data can become an issue, but sometimes that's the only way to get the performance that you need.

I seem to get asked that question at every job interview I go to:

> When would you denormalise a database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if those 40-50 columns are all dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key of the table.

Comment: You might still want to break up (a normalized) table for performance reasons if those columns are huge and rarely queried (vertical partitioning).

Comment: You might, but then you *might* do that in a table with 5 columns.  40 or 50 is not exactly a huge numnber.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you call normal. If you are a big enterprise corporation, it's not normal, because you have way too few columns.

But if you find it hard to work with that many columns, you probably have a problem and need to do something about it: either abstract the many columns away or split up your data model to something more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound very normalised, so you might want to look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) . But it really depends on what you're storing I suppose...

Comment: Without more info, you cannot really say that the table is not normalized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "normal", but it should not be causing any problems. If you have many "optional" columns, that are null most of the time, or many fields are very large and not often queried, then maybe the schema could be normalized or tuned a bit more, but the number of columns itself is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns has no relationship to whether the data is normalized or not. It is the content of the columns which will tell you that. Are the columns things like
Phone1, phone2, phone3? Then certainly the table is not normalized and should be broken apart. But if they are all differnt items which are all in a one-to-one raltionship with the key value, then 40-50 columns can be normalized.

This doesn't mean you always want to store them in one table though. If the combined size of those columns is larger than the actual bytes allowed per row of data in the database, you might be better off creating two or more tables in a one-to-one relationship with each other. Otherwise you will have trouble storing the data if all the fields are at or near their max size. And if some of the fields are not needed most of the time, a separate table may also be in order for them.